# AngularJS: display item number problems, using filter and ngtable pagination

Tags: angularjs, filter, pagination, ngtable

I am using NG-table to display filtered data but I encountered problem with the pagination.

This is the construction:

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="(type, value) in winetypes">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="winetypes[type]"/> {{type}}
</li>



<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="wine in data | winetypefilter:winetypes">
        {{wine.name}} is a {{wine.type}} with {{wine.style}} style from {{wine.country}}
    </li>
</ul>


<p><strong>Page:</strong> {{tableParams.page()}}</p>

<p><strong>Count per page:</strong> {{tableParams.count()}}</p>

<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in filtered = ($data | winetypefilter:winetypes)">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The filtering, and the pagination are working fine, but if the red checkbox is checked (red wines), all the filtered red wines appears inside a classic list (not linked to ng-table).

Normally inside the table created by ng-table, in each page it should appears 10 items, but it´'s not the case (see the image below)

**Here the demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/9xTdaQ2bTfY0jQpZAL1T?p=preview

[image: capture screen]

What is the way to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is being filtered *after* it is paged, which is why you aren't seeing 10 items in the grid.  You want to filter the data first, and *then* page it.  Filter the data in the controller instead of the view:

```
getData: function($defer, params) {
   var filteredData = $filter('winetypefilter')(data, $scope.winetypes);
   $defer.resolve(filteredData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
}
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in filtered = ($data)">
```

Since you aren't using the filter system that is built-in to ngTable, you need to manually refresh the data when the filter changes:

```
$scope.$watch("winetypes", function(newvalue, oldvalue) {
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
  });
}, true);
```

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459281/custom-filter-with-angularjs-ngtable) is doing something very similar to what you are doing.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/worVKsgcUiThH8v9BYtO?p=preview)