# Select filter in ngTable does not update when ngtable reload is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have a situation where I need to show all data on checkbox click, which reloads the ngtable, but the select filter does not load and shows previous value. Is there any other way to reload ngtable filters? Here is [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckku71M99fjpvWGvuwG9?p=preview) for the problem.

Code

```
<input id="datalabels" ng-model="taskCheckbox.isNormal" ng-change="allTaskCheckboxClicked(taskCheckbox.isNormal)" type="checkbox">
<label for="datalabels" style="font-weight:bold;">Show All Tasks</label>
<table ng-table="taskDetailTableParams" show-filter="true" class="table upgradeTaskDetailTable text-left table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in $data" height="10px" class="animate" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}">
            <td data-title="" class="text-center col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'ctaskId': 'select' }" sortable="'ctaskId'" filter-data="filterCTasks($column)">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.taskImage }}" title="{{ item.task }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" />
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Task Name'" class="text-left col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }" sortable="'name'">{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td data-title="'Type of Task'" class="text-center col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'type': 'text' }" sortable="'type'">{{item.type}}</td>
            <td data-title="'latest Run'" class="text-center col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'selectIdFor0': 'select' }" sortable="'selectIdFor0'" filter-data="filterStatusFor0($column)">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.statusImageFor0 }}" title="{{ item.statusFor0 }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" />
            </td>
            <td data-title="'2nd Latest Run'" class="text-center col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'selectIdFor1': 'select' }" sortable="'selectIdFor1'" filter-data="filterStatusFor1($column)">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.statusImageFor1 }}" title="{{ item.statusFor1 }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" />
            </td>
            <td data-title="'3rd Latest Run'" class="text-center col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" header-class="text-left" filter="{ 'selectIdFor2': 'select' }" sortable="'selectIdFor2'" filter-data="filterStatusFor2($column)">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.statusImageFor2 }}" title="{{ item.statusFor2 }}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$scope.filterCTasks = function(column) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(column));
    var def = $q.defer(),
        arr = [],
        filterStatus = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.taskDetailData, function(item) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(item.ctaskId, arr) === -1) {
            arr.push(item.ctaskId);
            filterStatus.push({
                'id': item.ctaskId,
                'title': item.task
            });
        }
    });
    filterStatus.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.id < b.id)
            return -1;
        if (a.id > b.id)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    def.resolve(filterStatus);
    return def;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using ng-grid.. it has lots of options http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/

Comment: @jos: we are using ngtable for our web app and most of the code is already written for ngtable.

Comment: If possible I would suggest testing your example with "ng-table": "~0.8.3", and see if your problem is resolved. There is a mode that enables binding to an array (without the need of implementing `getData`). Check this out http://ng-table.com/#/loading/demo-lazy-loaded